# How do I use npm@6.6.7 for my project when npm

Tags: node.js, npm-install, versioning, npm-package

6.6.7 is in my package-lock.json.
`npm view npm version` outputs 9.6.7.
`npm -v` outputs 9.5.1.
`npm list` outputs npm@9.6.7.
`npm list -g` outputs list including npm@9.6.7.
Node@18.16.0 is installed.
Anyone out there available to help me out with this one?

Comment: npm is included in nodejs; so take a look at `nvm`

Comment: I installed nvm and was finally able to update Node and thus npm. Thanks a ton for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade your npm version by executing:

```
npm install -g npm@X.Y.X
```

If you want to make sure the version you are looking for is the right one, you can check the [*version history page*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm?activeTab=versions).

By the way, if you're using Linux or macOs, you can use [*nvm*](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). It's pretty easy to install, and you can quickly alternate your Node enveironment.

Comment: Installation of nvm and a global update did the trick. Thanks for the comment.